# NHibernate and Unit of Work Pattern

Tags: nhibernate

Does NHibernate internally implement UnitOfWork Pattern? If NOT,  What are the cases when I should implement UoW pattern in Nhibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NHibernate `ISession` is the unit of work.